# scrollView issue in android

Tags: android

In my android appl;ication I am using a table inside a scrollview and below that there is a footer.
Now the issue is the last row of the table is covered by the footer and is not visible.
Is there any solution for this.
My layout xml is

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Scroll"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/SubTable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Please let me know your valuable suggestions.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give the footer a specific height and use this height as a negativ margin at the bottom for your ScrollView. Something like that: http://www.droidnova.com/layout-technique-static-elements-below-scrollview,123.html